# Compute intersection between bezier curve and a line

Tags: bezier-curve

Is there ready analytical solution of a set of two equations describes intersection between bezier curve and line

Answer (score 1):

In general, finding the intersection between a degree N Bezier curve and a line is the same as finding the roots of a degree N polynomial, which only has analytic solution when N is small (N <=4).